# Using Direct2D on a Direct3D device using slimDX

Tags: c#, slimdx

I've used easyhook to hook into a process's endScene function.

I want to use this newfound "power" to draw a simple rectangle on the screen (maybe even a gradient). But for this to go a little more smoothly i would like to use Direct2D (not the directX9 device that the process is using).

How do i use direct2d to draw stuff on a direct3d (DX9) device?